# abstract method in namespace

Tags: c++

i have quite strange problem.

I have 3 files:
figure.h:

```
#ifndef FIGURE_H
#define FIGURE_H
namespace figure
{
    class figure
    {
        public:
            figure(position &p,color c);
            virtual bool canMove(const position &p)=0;
            virtual bool move(const position &p)=0;
        protected:
            color col;
            position &p;
    };
    class king : public figure
    {
    };
};
#endif // FIGURE_H
```

king.h:

```
#ifndef KING_H
#define KING_H

#include "./figure.h"
namespace figure
{
   class king : protected figure
   {
   };
}
#endif // KING_H
```

and king.cpp:

```
#include "king.h"
bool figure::king::canMove(const position &p)
{
}
```

I'm compiling it with:
gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra

but the problem is that i got this error:

> /src/figure/figure.h:24:45: error: no ‘bool
>   figure::king::canMove(const position&)’ member function declared in
>   class ‘figure::king’

What should I do?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Namespaces and function bodies don't need semicolons after them.

Comment: @chris - post that as an answer

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel, I highly doubt that causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you haven't declared the method `canMove()`. Just declare it in class `king`

```
namespace figure
{
   class king : public figure
   {
   public:
       bool canMove(const position &p); 
   };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to *declare* that function in `class king`.

```
class king : public figure
{
  virtual bool canMove(const position &p) override;  // This was missing.
};
```

**Edit:**

> All derived classes must implement abstract functions if I'm not mistaken

That is incorrect.  You may want class `king` to *also* be an abstract class.  As with other class members, omitting the declaration above tells the compiler that `king::canMove` should inherit from `figure::canMove` - that it should still be pure virtual.

That's why you need the declaration above.

Comment: Seeing as this is tagged C++11, the function should be declared `virtual bool canMove(const position &p) override;`

Comment: Oh, my fault, its declared only once, in king.h. Why do I need to declare it again, if method is abstract? All derived classes must implement abstract functions if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @TomášČerník In C++, If you are overriding a function with different implementation its required to declare it explicitly in the header whether or not its abstract. This is because, the actual implementation in .C file might in a different library. So for the code that uses the header to compile, it has to know that its going to be implemented somewhere

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the compiler message, you need to `declare` `canMove(const position&)` inside `king` class.